# MySql find Duplicate IPaddress in table

Tags: php, mysql

I have saved `ipAddress` in table and I want to find which ip's are duplicate.

```
SELECT * FROM webInformation GROUP BY ipAddress
```

How to fix this MySql command?

Comment: Hint: what's the point of a group by without some aggregate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT `ip`, COUNT(*) cnt FROM `webInformation` GROUP BY `ip` HAVING cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by use of primary key and self Join.

Ex: your PK is **id** and table name ipTable

Query:

```
Select * from ipTable i1 JOIN ipTable i2
where i1.ipAddress IN(SELECT ipAddress from i2 where i2.id != i1.id);
```

Consider Logic Behind this query and apply same for yours.
Best Of Luck